# Как создать скролинг анимация ScrollView для обычного вью

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, ios9

Есть UIView на весь экран, необходимо создать анимацию как на UIScrollView (обычный скроллинг вверх и вниз с возвратом объекта в его первоначальное положение) есть идея реализовать при помощи UITouch Но может есть метод попроще ? Можно ли создать UIScrollView с размером во весь экран, и как-то прописать сто бы она анимировался ?

Comment: Почему не хотите Ваш UIView поместить в UIScrollView, если нужен простой скролл?

Comment: Если растянуть UIScrollView на размер экрана он не будет анимироваться, анимация начнется если UIScrollView расширить больше чем UIScreen. А мне нужен элемент с высотой UIScreen. (Заранее изменяюсь если не понятно изложил мысль)

Comment: Добавьте Ваш UIView в UIScrollView и пропишите  `scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`. Если то что нужно, перенесу в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное,  это свойство я и искал, если хотите можете перенести в ответ, я его апну.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте Ваш `UIView` в `UIScrollView` и пропишите:

```
[_scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
```

**Swift:**

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощ!